# ADB reverse socket to two or more emulators/devices on Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, adb, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase emulators to test my Android app. I'm trying to set up a testing environment where an Android emulator(AVD manager device) AND an android real device have access to my Firebase emulator real time database found on http://localhost:4000.

I can make both(real and virtual) devices, ***individually***, have access to the Firebase emulator database, but NOT both at the same time.

I have my real device connected via USB port and allowed USB debugging and my Android emulator running at the same time. Then, on the Android Studio platform-tools folder I opened up a command window and input the following:

```
adb reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000
```

This gives me an error: ***adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator***

Inside my firebase.json file found inside my Firebase emulator project I have the following set-up for connections to my database:

```
"database": {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 9000
},
```

**How can I make both (REAL and VIRTUAL) devices or two (Virtual) devices connect to Firebase emulator Real Time data base?**

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the device serialno

```
adb -s serialno reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000
```

or, `-d` and `-e` if you have one of each (emulator, device).

Additionally, to select the device interactively you can use this gist: https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4537110

Comment: Thank you Diego!  I tried the command: adb -s serialno reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000  AND replaced serialno with my real device serial no. AND it worked. BUT, it does not work with the emulator!  The emulator has a serial no. of type: EMULATOR30X5X5X0

Comment: Try `-e` if you have only 1 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Diego Torres Milano for pointing me in the right direction.

using the command:  **adb -s serialno reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000** will work!

*HOWEVER* you must FIRST run the command
***adb devices***

Once you run this command, you get all the serial no's of all the connected devices you have to ADB. Then, just run:
***adb -s serialno reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000*** using your desired device/emulator. It works for either real device or emulator!